# Filter range that in yours texts contains a values from anothers cells

Tags: arrays, regex, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula

[image]

I want to filter `column D` if in your texts there are specifically somewhere in them the values that are in `column B`.

What happens is that when I try to use the `SEARCH`, `FIND`, or `MATCH` functions, they return values that I am not looking for.

What am i going wrong?

For example: `england/premier-league/` is in `column C` and is in the `D2`, but this value is not returned. And others not in `column C` appear in the filter. But they should not appear.

Link to Spreadsheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mwK3VaobYkbltx8gnE8b8Jf7TShn3VoYrQfMTuolIWQ/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this:

```
=FILTER(D:D, REGEXMATCH(D:D, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, B:B)))
```

[image: 0]